# Is there a way to get perfectly smooth normals on a cylinder that is tapered like a cone?

Tags: modeling, normals

I have a cylinder with 24 faces that I tapered so it is shaped like a cone, but the normals get sharp looking, as you can see here:
[image: Notice the banding in the middle. The normals appear smooth toward the top and bottom.]

The normals appear to be facing in the propper direction:
[image]

I've tried "Shade smooth", I've tried adjusting the "auto smooth" and I've tried with and without end-cap faces, and I've tried with and without adding extra edge loops towards the top and bottom, and I've tried with and without extra subdivisions along the length of it.
The faces are planar quads, so I'm unsure why they appear this way. Is there a way to fix this? It even shows up like this in Unity too.

Comment: I can make it appear smooth by having lots of vertical subdivision to the point that the faces are more square than rectangular, but that's just "solving" the problem by creating another problem of having way too much geo.

Comment: Are you willing to consider shader-based solutions?

Comment: @Nathan, well, the thing is I am using this geo in Unity and specifically when I'm making my own shader for it it causes issues. My shader looks perfectly smooth until I do anything involving the normals.

Comment: That makes it sound like something else is your issue.  I'd want to know what you're doing with normals.  Specular?  Or something different?  In any case, you can make a perfect normal map for a cone using shader nodes-- but yeah, the geo leaves something to be desired, and although you can minimize the issue, I know of no way to get base normals on a cone perfect.  Note that the simplest way to solve, good normals without too much geo, is to just bake high-to-low normals.

Comment: I'm simply adding a fresnel effect (dot product of normal direction and view direction). Even simply visualizing the normals (plugging normals straight into Albedo or Emission) reveals the terrible normals. What do you mean by "bake high-to-low normals?"

Comment: "What do you mean by "bake high-to-low normals?" Google "blender how to bake normal map for unity".

Comment: Ah, I know what you are talking about now. That doesn't solve the problem, as the vertex normals are the issue. I shouldn't have to use a normal map.

Comment: You can use that to get high poly normals onto the low poly, so that you have the benefits of high poly cone (good normals) and the benefits of low poly cone (few vertices.)  Vertex normals are not the issue-- they are identical between high and low poly.  Interpolation along the faces is what is bad.  Vertex normals will not solve the problem on a low poly.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is due to "long inner" triangles.

To lower this effect, add some loop cuts:

[image]

Comment: His comment under the question sounds as if this is not what he wants. But I would do it like that as well because that's basically the only way.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann, Ben talk about a lot of vertical subdiv... I don't think four loop cuts is "a lot"... but we'll see!

Comment: No, it isn't... but your cone is wider at the bottom. The narrower it is, the worse the shading gets ;)